# Trying to add a "SharepointDocumentLocation" to MS Dynamics365 via the Web API

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, odata, webapi

I'm trying to create new Sharepoint document locations in my Dynamics365 (in the cloud) system, and I'm trying to link those to an existing Sharepoint Site (collection), as well as to a custom entity of my own.

I tried to do this:

```
POST /api/data/v9.2/sharepointdocumentlocations

Accept:application/json
Authorization: Bearer (valid JWT token)
Content-Type:application/json
OData-Version: 4.0
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0

{
    "name": "WebDocuments",
    "description": "Some useful description",
    "sharepointdocumentlocation_parent_sharepointsite@odata.bind" : "sharepointsites(0f66e9e3-5dfc-ec11-82e5-0022489f9669)",
    "relativeurl": "site",
    "customEntity_SharePointDocumentLocations@odata.bind": "my_customentity(a654d179-ab61-ec11-8f8f-000d3a64d05c)"
}
```

but no matter what I try, I keep getting errors - mostly along the lines of:

> An error occurred while validating input parameters: Microsoft.OData.ODataException: An undeclared property 'sharepointdocumentlocation_parent_sharepointsite' which only has property annotations in the payload but no property value was found in the payload. In OData, only declared navigation properties and declared named streams can be represented as properties without values.

I have been researching and found several blog posts offering help - unfortunately, none of that has helped me solve my issue.

I tried to use various field names:

- `sharepointdocumentlocation_parent_sharepointsite@odata.bind`
- `ParentLocationOrSite`

and quite a few more - yet without any success.

Any ideas? How can I create a new Sharepoint document location in Dynamics365, and set its `ParentLocationOrSite` and `RegardingObjectId` properties in the POST request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax for that field should be:

`parentsiteorlocation_sharepointsite@odata.bind`

as you have another lookup pointing to a custom entity, I suggest to use my tool [Dataverse REST Builder](https://github.com/GuidoPreite/DRB) to create the Web API requests.

Comment: Thanks - and **great tool**! Makes a lot of things a lot easier - marvellous! I was able to get this to work now finally - you've saved my bacon :-)